# GIS "hack": ways arbitarily assigning coordinate in order to match the raster and vector layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, georeferencing, mapwindow

Before I raise my question, I have to admit that I am a total newer on GIS, I don't have much background on GIS. But suddenly I need to take over the GIS job from a GIS specialist who just left the office. And since time is a luxury for me right now, I am looking for some "hack" to fix my immediate problem.

The task is below: 
I need to spot out which bed in an elderly home belongs to a male or female resident, and present it visually on a map.

The materials are below:
- A raw map from the elderly home, marked the bed no for each bed
- A spreadsheet contain the bed no and the gender of the resident on that bed

What I have done till now:
- "digitize" the raw map: I have used MapWindows and created a vector layer consist of beds, something like creating a new layer on photoshop, and then trace the bed on the new layer
- created a new project in QGIS, import the raw map as raster layer, the bed layer (vector layer created by MapWindows), and the spreadsheet as csv
- in QGIS, I have joint the bed layer with the csv file correctly
- made adjustment in the "Style" tab of the bed layer (vector) so that the gender of each bed can be shown

I think I am almost there, but problem arise:
- in Mapwindows, both the raw map and the vector layer matched perfectly (i.e. I draw the trace the bed on the new layer and both the raster and vector layer align to each other perfectly)
- this is not the case in QGIS

I am thinking of something like "georeferencing" issue, which the GIS specialist keep saying before, but I don't know what the hack it is.

I need to "realign" the raster and vector layer, how can I do it?

Comment: Find out which coordinate you used when digitizing in Mapwindow. Select the same in QGIS. That should do it.

Comment: You may also want to get the [QGIS manual](http://www.qgis.org/en/documentation/manuals.html) and look at section 12.8 (Georeferencer Plugin). That has steps to show you how to line up your raster map with your vectors.

Comment: mapwindow probably allows something like an arbitrary xy cs. which meand the system hasn't been assigned and it just places the data where the coordinates fall. since all the coordinates are the same it overlays correctly. Qgis doesn't allow this.

Comment: thanks guy for the help, I accidentally found that I can use the georeferencer in MapWindow and click 3 points to set up the coordinate, I use the same coordinate as I click on the map, and it is OK now. Thanks again.